# Why does an AVL tree with N nodes maintain C<=N/2?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

If C denotes the number of "only child" nodes (a node is called an only child when its parent is not null && it doesn't have a sibling), why do we have that for every AVL tree with N nodes : C<=(N/2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an AVL tree of height 1 (i.e. consisting only of the root): The condition clearly holds (N=1, C=0).

Now consider the AVL trees of height 2. There can be either a root with 2 children (N=3, C=0) or a root with one child (N=2, C=1). Thus the condition also holds for trees of height 2.

Now assume, the condition holds for trees of height h (h>=2) and h-1, we show that it then also holds for a tree of height h+1. We can construct a tree with height h+1 by taking a new root with one child of height h and the other child of height h or h-1. These are the only allowed configurations that keep the AVL property intact. Neither the new root nor the roots of the two subtrees are "only child" nodes. We have therefore N=1+N1+N2 and C=C1+C2. Since C1<=N1/2 and C2<=N2/2 we get also C<=N/2.

Now, by induction the condition holds for AVL trees of all heights.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!!